# How to calculate steps of a Markov chain with an unknown probability?

Tags: markov-chains

I have the matrix:

```
  A     B     C
A 0.80  0.10  0.10
B 0.2   0.75  0.05
C 0.10  0.10  0.80
```

They ask me: if $ A $ is 40% right now, what's the probability of $A$ after two passes?

I proposed solving as

$$
\left( \begin{array}{ccc}0.4 & b & (0.6-b)\end{array} \right)
\left( \begin{array}{ccc}
0.8 & 0.1 & 0.1 \\
0.2 & 0.75 & 0.05 \\
0.1 & 0.1 & 0.8
\end{array} \right)^2
$$

But I can't find how to get $ P_0(B)=b $.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose that the matrix squaring is done.
So,
$$
\left(\begin{array}
\  P_2(A)&P_2(B)&P_2(C)
\end{array}\right)=$$
$$=\left( \begin{array}{ccc}0.4 & b & (0.6-b)\end{array} \right)
\left( \begin{array}{ccc}
0.8 & 0.1 & 0.1 \\
0.2 & 0.75 & 0.05 \\
0.1 & 0.1 & 0.8 
\end{array} \right)^2=$$
$$=\left( \begin{array}{ccc}0.4 & b & (0.6-b)\end{array} \right)
\left( \begin{array}{ccc}
a_{1,1} & a_{1,2} & a_{1,3} \\
a_{2,1} & a_{2,2} & a_{2,3} \\
a_{3,1} & a_{3,2} & a_{3,3}
\end{array} \right)=$$
$$=\left( \begin{array}{ccc}
0.4\cdot a_{1,1} + b\cdot a_{2,1} + (0.6-b)\cdot a_{3,1} \\
0.4\cdot a_{1,2} + b\cdot a_{2,2} + (0.6-b)\cdot a_{3,2} \\
0.4\cdot a_{1,3} + b\cdot a_{2,3} + (0.6-b)\cdot a_{3,3}
\end{array} \right)^T.$$
From here

$$P_2(A)=0.4\cdot a_{1,1} + b\cdot a_{2,1} + (0.6-b)\cdot a_{3,1}$$
and indeed, $0\le b \le 0.6$ is unknown. But this means only that $P_2(A)$ depends on $P_0(B)=b$. This is not counter intuitive.